# How to use promises with recursive fetch?

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, fetch

I am using fetch to retrieve a tree, one layer at a time. How can I trigger an action after all branches have been fetched? The tree has multiple branches and I don't know the depth in advance.

Pseudo-code:

```
until Children is empty fetchChildren()

after all children are retrieved doSomething()
```

I found some answers, but they only deal with chained then(), not trees.

[edit] Although not mandatory, I am hoping that the solution can run in IE11. I am already using promise and fetch polyfills.

Comment: `Promise.all()` for each layer?

Comment: That would work for a single layer, but doSomething should only run after ALL layers and sub-layers have been fetched. And I don't know in advance how many there are. So basically I am looking for a recursive Promise.all().

Answer (score 2):

Just first wait for the layer elements to be fetched, then recursively proceed with the childrens and await that:

```
async function fetchChildren(layer) {
  await Promise.all(layer.map(fetch));
  await Promise.all(layer.map(el => fetchChildren(el.children)));
}
```

(*fetch(el) has to be a promising function*)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with a recursive async function waiting for the fetching of an element's children to be done, before returning a promise.

That way, we can call `doSomething` when everything is done.

```js
const tree = {
  url: 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cevhxOsZnS',
  children: [{
    url: 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cguaPsRxAi'
  }, {
    url: 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cguaPsRxAi',
    children: [{
      url: 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfDZdmxnDm'
    }]
  }]
};

function doSomething() {
  console.log("doing something");
}

async function fetchIt(element) {
  if (element.children) {
    await Promise.all(element.children.map(fetchIt));
  }
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("fetching " + element.url);
    fetch(element.url).then(res => {
      console.log("done");
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

fetchIt(tree).then(doSomething);
```

Comment: This is overcomplicating it a lot.

Comment: @Christophe I admit the generator method was kinda complicated and didn't involve a recursive fetch anyway. I edited my answer.